# mouseover and mouseleave text color changing not working within directive link

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive with transclude feature, the directive is working fine but the issue is that, in the child transcluded template I am having a text say "Some-Name", when mouse is hovered the color of the text should be white and when mouse leaves it should be the color which has been assigned actually. I need to implement this without external css file

I have tried with the following code, but it seems not working

```
elem.find("a").bind("mouseover", function()
{
    scope.actualColor = angular.copy(scope.textColor.color);
    scope.textColor.color = "#000000";
});
elem.find("a").bind("mouseleave", function()
{
    scope.textColor.color = scope.actualColor;
});
```

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/fKbHKH4bnjtRcZy4A0Zg?p=preview)**

Can anyone please tell me some solutions for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to bind the events which are outside the `AngularJs` world, `AngularJs` can't detect any change. You need to use `scope.$apply()` to let `AngularJs` knows that there are some changes on the `scope`:

```
        elem.find("a").bind("mouseover", function()
        {
            scope.actualColor = angular.copy(scope.textColor.color);
            scope.textColor.color = "#000000";
            scope.$apply();

        });
        elem.find("a").bind("mouseleave", function()
        {
            scope.textColor.color = scope.actualColor;
            scope.$apply();
        });
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eaqI9nvoNntPRWCFp87Z?p=preview).

Comment: nice catch @LVarayut,  its working in the plunker which you have given here check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yvfXTiev5XIOIzFSRdJO?p=preview) I have implemented the same scenario in which I have applied for a drop-down list, but after adding the mouseover and mouseleave listener the option list is closing and the hover feature is not working, check line 56- 67

Comment: Any idea on that issue

Comment: @Alex, You could try to solve it yourself at this moment. I'll take a look at it when I arrived my home.

Comment: @AlexMan I have looked at your updated plunkr. I have seen this kind of problem before. You might need to use the [Bootstrap dropdowns enhancement plugin](http://behigh.github.io/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/#inputs-noclose).

Comment: @AlexMan, I figured it out in another way to do it. Please check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rG7qt48z7tMcPd64OkNL?p=preview). Hope that helps.

Comment: when i applied the same stuff to parent then its working in different way . check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8PIBdCk9Xz5TLerZalSp?p=preview)

Comment: @AlexMan, you should apply the style to the first-child of the `a` tag in your parent. See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lU3mFaXfEhFUxIomPV1S?p=preview). Consider to open a new question, if you have any further question because it's far out of your original question.

Comment: I have open a new  question over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491484/alternative-for-first-in-jqlite