# alternative for .first() in jqlite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have created a drop-down using angularjs directive, the directive is working fine, right now I writing all the css within the directive itself, In one of the feature when the mouse hovers the drop-down list options it should change the background color to `#27A1EC` - blue, and text color to white, on mouse leave then the background color to be white and text color to be the actual color, everything is working fine but one issue I am facing is that since we don't have JQuery `.find()` option in JQLite I have tried using like as shown below

I have used `angular.element(document.querySelector('#parent'))` instead of `elm.find('a').first()`, I don't whether this is correct or not

```
 elm.find("a").bind("mouseover", function() {
        scope.actualColor = scope.textColor.color;
        //elm.find('a').first().css('color', 'white').css('background-color', '#27A1EC');
        angular.element(document.querySelector('#parent')).css('color', 'white').css('background-color', '#27A1EC');
      });

 elm.find("a").bind("mouseleave", function() {
        //elm.find('a').first().css('color', scope.actualColor).css('background-color', 'white');
        angular.element(document.querySelector('#parent')).css('color', scope.actualColor).css('background-color', 'white');
      });
```

Now when I hover the mouse to **Parent2** within the drop-down list the hover color changing is redirecting and is applying to **Parent1**

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this,

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2GEwx4JuyWLQjrgUqlg0?p=preview)**

Comment: ID of an element must be unique....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the problem is you have multiple elements with the id parent, so when using querySelector it will return the first element with the id `parent`.

You can use [.eq(0)](http://api.jquery.com/eq) instead of [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first)

```
elm.find('a').eq(0).css('color', 'white');
```

---

But a better solution will be is to assign a class parent to the parent element instead of id like

```
<a class='parent' href='#' ng-click='getValue(optGroupLabel,optGroupValue)'>{{optGroupLabel}}<span class='value'>{{optGroupValue}}</span></a>
```

then

```
angular.element(elm[0].querySelector('.parent')).css('color', scope.actualColor).css('background-color', 'white');
```